# Firefox addon: return focus to input element after closing of Panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an extension to generate passwords. It has a Button and a Panel. Button opens Panel, Panel loads html with JS, and all works good.
On keyUp in the panel I generate password and propagate it to the page with ".port.emit" scheme. In there I make "document.activeElement.value = pass" and that's okay, it works.
Then, the Panel closes, and user wants to submit the form, but there is no focus in that field (or form)! User must click submit button with mouse.
I've tried .focus() but it seems that the focus is somewhere else, not on the page at all.

How can I return the focus to the page itself after Panel hides?

main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var { Hotkey } = require("sdk/hotkeys");

// Create a button
var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "show-panel",
  label: "myPass",
  icon: {
    "16": "./padlock-16.png",
    "32": "./padlock-32.png",
    "64": "./padlock-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

var currentUrl = '';

// Show the panel when the user clicks the button.
function handleClick(state) {
  currentUrl = tabs.activeTab.url;
  pass_panel.show();
  //if (tabs.activeTab.url)
  //  console.log('Current url is: ' + tabs.activeTab.url);
}

var hotKey = Hotkey({
  combo: "f9",
  onPress: function() {
    handleClick();
  }
});

// Construct a panel, loading its content from the "text-entry.html"
// file in the "data" directory, and loading the "get-text.js" script
// into it.
var pass_panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  position: button,
  contentURL: data.url("addon.htm"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("addon.js")
});

// When the panel is displayed it generated an event called
// "show": we will listen for that event and when it happens,
// send our own "show" event to the panel's script, so the
// script can prepare the panel for display.
pass_panel.on("show", function() {
  pass_panel.port.emit("show", currentUrl);
});

pass_panel.on("hide", function() {
  pass_panel.port.emit("hide");
  var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("page.js")
  });
  worker.port.emit("focusPass");
});

// Listen for messages called "text-entered" coming from
// the content script. The message payload is the text the user
// entered.
// In this implementation we'll just log the text to the console.
pass_panel.port.on("text-entered", function (text) {
  //console.log(text);
  var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("page.js")
  });
  worker.port.emit("enterPass", text);
  require('sdk/timers').setTimeout(closePanel, 5000);
});

function closePanel() {
  pass_panel.hide();
}
```

addon.js (loaded from  tag in Panel's addon.html):

```
var passArea = document.getElementById("pass");
self.port.on("show", function onShow(name) {
  passArea.focus();
});

self.port.on("hide", function onHide() {
  resultArea.value = '';
  passArea.value = '';
})

var resultArea = document.getElementById("result");
resultArea.addEventListener('keyup', function onkeyup(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
  // Remove the newline.
    text = resultArea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    self.port.emit("text-entered", text);
  }
}, false);
```

page.js:

```
var passWindow = document.activeElement;
// "self" is a global object in content scripts
// Listen for a "enterPass"
self.port.on("enterPass", function(pass) {
  passWindow.value = pass;
});

self.port.on("focusPass", function() {
  console.log("focusing!");
  passWindow.focus();
});
```

The latter passWindow.focus(); doesn't work, because the page is not focused at all :(

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •**the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: We generally try to provide answers that are tested and working. If we are going to try to verify our solution works *for you* it is *MUCH* easier to do so if we have your code to start from rather than having to make it all up. To do so, we each have to first duplicate the problem you are having then find a solution. Not having source code in the form of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes helping you a *LOT* more work. Without such code there is less incentive to find an answer for you.

Comment: You can use Services.focus which uses nsIFocusManager to get the last focused element.

Comment: Added the code. If you have some questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: Did yo ucheck out nsIFocusManager? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFocusManager#Attributes

Comment: @Noitidart I've tried to use it like this:
    var { Cc } = require("chrome");
    var focusManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/focus-manager;1"];
    focusManager.setFocus(focusElement, focusManager.FLAG_BYKEY);
but it gives me an error: focusManager.setFocus is not a function

Comment: First import services like this ` var { Cc, Cu } = require("chrome"); Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm')` @RomanQuick try this: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/bbceda2c3ddad51f6b72